# Help with ruby and def respond_to?(method,*args, &block) in library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a Gem that deals with images that get modified.  I want to modify it to update the old image but, I need to be able to get the object id.

Right now it uses the following code:

```
def respond_to?(method,*args, &block)
puts ("++++METHOD #{method.to_s} ARGS #{args} BLOCK #{block}")
args.each do |value|
  puts ("ARGS #{value}")
 end
```

but I don't know how to get id from something I pass in nor do I know how to pass the id in, I've tried
`@asset.image.s_245_245(:asset_id=>@asset.id)` with no success.  Args returns nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I am currently reading http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/09/inside-ruby-on-rails-extract_options-from-arrays/

**Update:** This too returned blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. How is the method `respond_to?` related to your problem with object id?

I am *guessing* that in reality you wanted to override `method_missing`, because now you do not call `respond_to?`, or it is not shown in your examples.

If you have not defined such method, calling `image.s_245_245` will trigger `method_missing` *(in the `image` object)* with the parameters you used for `respond_to?`.

There is a rule, which says that if you use `method_missing` to handle some calls, then you should *also* modify `respond_to?`, and make it returning true when asked for the methods handled by `method_missing`.

As for object ID, there are two possibilities:

- Every object in ruby responds to `.object_id` (which returns an internal identifier of every object)
- ActiveRecord objects respond to `.id` (which is a primary key in the database).

This is just a side-note, because I suppose that if you start experimenting with `method_missing` instead of `respond_to?` you will know which one you want.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, but yes it was method_missing that I wanted.